# Remove item by name in Firebase React-Native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am trying to remove/delete items from my Firebase Database onPress of a button. The following is my code for the method I'm using to attempt to remove the item.

```
let itemsRef = db.ref('/items');

handleRemove = (item) => {

    itemsRef.remove({
      name: item
    });
}
```

My method for remove is the same implementation of the push method that adds items to the database.

I get an error stating that - "Error: Reference.remove failed: first argument must be a valid function"

[See image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlzs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remove` method doesnt take an object as a parameter. You should only do this:

```
itemsRef.remove();
```

From the docs:

> [remove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove)
>
> remove(onComplete?: function): Promise
>
> Removes the data at this Database location.
>
> Any data at child locations will also be deleted.
>
> The effect of the remove will be visible immediately and the corresponding event 'value' will be triggered. Synchronization of the remove to the Firebase servers will also be started, and the returned Promise will resolve when complete. If provided, the onComplete callback will be called asynchronously after synchronization has finished